# Input field giving error at "value" in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react"

const Loginform =() =>{
    const [name, setName] = useState<String | null>();
    const [fullname, setFullname] = useState<String | null>();
    const inputEvent =(event: { target: { value: SetStateAction< String |null | undefined  >; }; })=>{
       
        setName(event.target.value)
    }
    const Submit = ()=>{
        setFullname(name)
    }
    return <>
    <h1>Enter Your Name </h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={inputEvent} value={name}/>
    <button onClick={Submit}>Submit</button>
    <h1>Hi {fullname==null? "Guest" :fullname}</h1>
    </>
}
export default Loginform
```

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={inputEvent} value={name}/>
```

Error is showing on "value" property in the above line

This is the error detail:

```
(property) React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.value?: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined
Type 'String | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2398, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
```

Tried writing return `as any` as well. Or tried adding `string[]`, but it's giving error.

Comment: You are setting your `name` state variable type as `<String | null>` (with uppercase `S`) try setting it to `<string | null>` (lowercase `s`) and see if you still ave the issue

Comment: I tried it. I have corrected the code now. pls check. This is giving me error

Comment: Is the `null` option causing the problem?  Why do you need your types to also include `null` and not just rely on `undefined`?

Comment: No. its not the null issue. I tried. Basically what is the return type of event.target.value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following adjustments:

- Replace `String` with `string` as primitive Typescript types are lowercase (`number, string, boolean, etc`)
- TypeScript is reporting this error because the property value does not accept `null` as a value but `undefined` instead. Update the code to:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<string>()
```

This initializes the state with `string` as the default type.
The initial state is implicitly considered as `undefined` because TypeScript sets the default value for a type to `undefined` if not explicitly provided.

- For simplicity, you don't need to destructure the event. Use inline functions like the example below:

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a CodeSanbox using your code and it seems to work fin with only few modifications.

You can find the [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-bas-hqjl2q?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0006356iro908ah6%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0002356ir2fcpdff%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0003356iyl90e9fm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0005356i8tub259v%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr9bknyr0002356ir2fcpdff%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyq0001356img1ueq0u%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0002356ir2fcpdff%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyq0001356img1ueq0u%2522%257D%252C%2522clr9bknyr0005356i8tub259v%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0004356iihxjikkh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0005356i8tub259v%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0004356iihxjikkh%2522%257D%252C%2522clr9bknyr0003356iyl90e9fm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr9bknyr0003356iyl90e9fm%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Here is the code I came up with

```
import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

const Loginform = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string | null>();
  const [fullname, setFullname] = useState<string | null>();
  const inputEvent = (event: {
    target: { value: SetStateAction<string | null | undefined> };
  }) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };
  const Submit = () => {
    setFullname(name);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Enter Your Name </h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        onChange={inputEvent}
        value={name}
      />
      <button onClick={Submit}>Submit</button>
      <h1>Hi {fullname == null ? "Guest" : fullname}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Loginform;
```